# How do I make a java file executable in Intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Hi I'm new to Java and imported a preexisting project (https://github.com/balanced/balanced-java) using Maven. While the tests are all runnable and passing, I am unable to run the RenderScenarios.java file (https://github.com/balanced/balanced-java/blob/master/src/scenarios/RenderScenarios.java).

When I try the following via the command line:

> javac src/scenarios/RenderScenarios.java

It raises the following errors:

```
src/scenarios/RenderScenarios.java:2: package com.fasterxml.jackson.databind does not exist
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
                                     ^
src/scenarios/RenderScenarios.java:3: package com.fasterxml.jackson.databind does not exist
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
                                     ^
src/scenarios/RenderScenarios.java:4: package net.asfun.jangod.template does not exist
import net.asfun.jangod.template.TemplateEngine;
                                ^
src/scenarios/RenderScenarios.java:16: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class TemplateEngine
location: class RenderScenarios
    final static TemplateEngine engine;
                 ^
src/scenarios/RenderScenarios.java:22: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JsonMappingException
location: class RenderScenarios
    public static Map<String, Object> loadScenarioCache() throws IOException, JsonMappingException {
                                                                              ^
src/scenarios/RenderScenarios.java:124: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JsonMappingException
location: class RenderScenarios
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JsonMappingException {
                                                               ^
src/scenarios/RenderScenarios.java:18: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class TemplateEngine
location: class RenderScenarios
        engine = new TemplateEngine();
                     ^
src/scenarios/RenderScenarios.java:26: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ObjectMapper
location: class RenderScenarios
                new ObjectMapper().readValue(cacheJson, HashMap.class);
```

However, the packages all exist in my external library, and I can even jump to the definitions / source from the IDE.

Comment: You need to set your classpath.

Comment: Why do you use javac if you are using IntelliJ? IntelliJ should be able to handle all compilation (and dependency issues). Also as @RobbyCornelissen commented, you might need to set your classpath.

Comment: ... that being said the latest version of the pom.xml file (which handles the dependencies) have the "jackson-databind" dependency (it has the package com.fasterxml.jackson.databind) commented out (since the March 6 commit 21f82b92c1442e64736cd99de3aab5c72f3cb079, see: https://github.com/balanced/balanced-java/commit/21f82b92c1442e64736cd99de3aab5c72f3cb079).